# Is torque due to gravity about the center of mass zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

I know torque due to Fg is zero on a level rod. However if the rod is tilted like below, is the torque still zero? The pivot point is on the center of mass. [image]

Comment: Yes, by definition of the center of mass, the torque of a distributed load like gravity is zero. Hence center of gravity = center of mass.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for Torque is:
$$ \tau = r \times  F$$
This is another way of saying that only forces that act perpendicular to the radial direction contribute to the net torque.

In the image below, the forces have been drawn acting downwards, but the principle is identical and this way seems more intuitive to me.

[image]

The key to understanding why the net torque is zero, is to understand that for every value of $\theta$ the lengths of the two red lines remains the same as one another. Since the direction and magnitude of the force of weight remains unchanged, $r$ is the only thing that can change the net torque, but since the two red lines will always be equal in length, there will always be an opposing and equal torque, resulting in zero net torque.

Comment: So intuitively speaking, if you slightly tilt a heavy rod pivoted at its centre, it would not rotate due to its weight ?

Comment: Yes. You would have to release it very carefully, and the rod would need to be of constant density

Comment: @wonderginwhy This would basically be a test of the uniformity of the rod given that you could actually place the pivot at the geometrical midpoint.

Comment: I'm balancing a pencil on my finger. If I slightly nudge it from one side, it rotates and falls. Why is that ?

Comment: Balancing a pencil on your finger, and a rod rotating around a fixed pivot are two very different scenarios. 1. The pencil is likely not of uniform density. 2. And most importantly, whether of not the pencil falls, is a question of friction between your finger and the pencil.

Comment: CM displaces due to slipping between finger and pencil, hence creating torque about your finger, ig

Answer (score 1):

[image]

At the Center of gravity :

$$F_1+F_2=M\,g\quad,\Rightarrow
F_2=M\,g-F_1$$

the torque about the center of gravity is:

$$\tau=F_1\,\cos(\psi)\,a-F_2\,\cos(\psi)\,b$$
thus

$$\tau\left(F_1~,F_2=M\,g-F_1\right)= 0$$

only if $~F_1=M\,g\frac{b}{a+b}~$

Answer (score -1):

The torque depends on the horizontal distance to the force, so it is still zero.